# How to put your symbol explanation for the formula?

Tags: equations, amsmath, math-operators

I have a formula written in LaTeX. What is the best way to explain what the symbols mean in the formula?

For example I have this equation with a where: symbol definitions

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\omega_MM_i+\omega_PP_i+\omega_TT_i\right)\omega_i}{n}\\
\text{where}
\text{n = amount of weeks}
\text{M = Missed}
...
\end{equation}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd write the explanation before or after the equation, using plain language: `where $n$ is the number of weeks, $M$ the missed weeks,...`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I often use `\intertext{}` from `amsmath` or `\shortintertext{}` from the `mathtools` package when this text needs to be interspersed within a set of equations. But in this case since you only have one equation, egreg's suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using a formula that introduces new variables I would try very hard to describe them in the text, either immediately before, or immediately after the formula.

Something like

[image]

or

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Assuming that $n$ is the number of weeks, and $M$ 
represents `Missed', then a formula for something is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\omega_MM_i+\omega_PP_i+\omega_TT_i\right)\omega_i}{n}
\end{equation}

The formula for something is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\omega_MM_i+\omega_PP_i+\omega_TT_i\right)\omega_i}{n}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is the number of weeks, and $M$ represents `Missed'.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a dedicated package, such as [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) (or [`listofsymbols`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listofsymbols)). These are able to produce a list of all symbols used in formulae all over the document (in a separate section, usually placed at the beginning of a document), sort them, etc.

I recommend this only if you have lots of formulae and/or a long document.

Comment: ... and consistent notations throughout the document, and only for symbols which are used at several places, I would add.

Answer (score 3):

On page 114 of [A comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) you can edit the code and obtain the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\@fleqntrue
\let\old@mathmargin=\@mathmargin
\@mathmargin=-1sp
\let\oldmathindent=\mathindent
\let\mathindent=\@mathmargin
\newsavebox{\myendhook} % for the tabulars
\def\tagform@#1{{(\maketag@@@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{% after the equation number
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{\usebox{\myendhook}}}%
  \global\sbox{\myendhook}{}% empty box
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sbox{\myendhook}{%
\begin{footnotesize}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{$=$\,}l}
$n$ & amount of weeks\\
$M$ & Missed
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}}
%
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\omega_MM_i+\omega_PP_i+\omega_TT_i\right)\omega_i}{n}\,;
\end{equation}
%
\sbox{\myendhook}{}% reset
%
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{\left(\omega_MM_i+\omega_PP_i+\omega_TT_i\right)\omega_i}{n}\,;\qquad
\qquad\parbox{4.0cm}{\footnotesize$\begin{aligned} n &= \text{ amount of weeks}\\[-1.0ex] M &= \text{ Missed}\end{aligned}$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

or use a `\parbox` as in the second example. This yields:

[image]